# Get URL or domain name of method that invokes my AWS Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I deployed an AWS Lambda (serverless) webhook that listens to activities from 2 different sites. [www.domain-1.com](http://www.domain-1.com) and [www.domain-2.com](http://www.domain-2.com). I want to be able to tell which of the two sites invoked my lambda function. I'm monitoring CloudWatch, and both `event` and `context` don't seem to have this info. For the context, I only see this:

```
  callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: [Getter/Setter],
  succeed: [Function (anonymous)],
  fail: [Function (anonymous)],
  done: [Function (anonymous)],
  functionVersion: '$LATEST',
  functionName: 'my-lambda-function-name',
  memoryLimitInMB: '512',
  logGroupName: '/aws/lambda/my-lambda-function',
  logStreamName: '2023/12/06/[$LATEST]6218198ee12a4182aab6362f30a60xxx',
  clientContext: undefined,
  identity: undefined,
  invokedFunctionArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:867281122000:function:my-lambda-function',
  awsRequestId: '1da1b5a7-f867-48c9-a749-9c6d582e3xxx',
  getRemainingTimeInMillis: [Function: getRemainingTimeInMillis]
}
```

Comment: I assume you are using API Gateway? If so here are the docs on event body. It looks like there may be a `event.requestContext.identity.sourceIp` which you may be able to use to identify the caller. If you also control the services you could have them send headers to identify. I think probably the better path would be to use API Key and usage plans and give each caller a separate one which would  and identify using the `x-api-key` header with their own key. Then you wouldn't have to "trust" their identification headers. If you give me some more context I can post a real answer.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. No, I have not set up API Gateway yet. Just Lambda function. Can it not be done without an API Gateway? Should I set it up as HTTP API or REST API?

Comment: So you are invoking from the other services using IAM authentication already using the lambda invocation API (IE AWS SDK or awscli)? IIRC, serverless framework sets up a regional api gateway RestAPI by default. I really need to know the mechanism by which the two remote servers push events (invoke) the function. Is it via HTTP requests?

Comment: It's a NodeJs app using the Serverless Framework. I deployed it using Terraform. Correct, I'm using IAM authentication, and have added permissions such as CreateLogGroup, CreateLogStream, CreateNetworkInterface, PutLogEvents, etc. Basically what this Lambda function does is watch the checkout process of two e-commerce sites. I need to know which domain triggered this Lambda function so I will know which database to access/update.

Comment: The IAM role you described sounds like the Lambda VPC execution role. I was referring to the caller (IE one of your services you are watching). How is the lambda "listening" for events, are the events HTTP requests sent fro the upstream services? Are they CloudWatch events pushed by those servers which then trigger the lambda? I'm now assuming they are not using the `lambda:invokeFunction` API directly or they would need their own IAM roles with `lambda:InvokeFunction` permission.

Comment: Serverless framework generates cloudformation templates. Can you see any `AWS::ApiGateway::RestAPI` or other `AWS::ApiGateway` resources in the resulting cloudformation stack?

Comment: If it is using HTTP as the event protocol, you should check this repo out, just ignore the fact that this uses a custom docker-based runtime, or that it's python... it's still a lambda (shameless self plug):
https://github.com/HarryCaveMan/lambda-embeddings-huggingface/blob/main/cft.yaml

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I abandoned this approach and instead deployed two Lambda functions. First for domain1 and the second for domain2. Then I used EventBridge rules to specify a constants whose values I retrieve when executing the function. They provide me with the info that I need.